# Exception while executing load dots command on domino server

Tags: lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

I am newbie in DOTs programming. I Installed a Domino server 9.0 social edition as enterprise server.

I think DOTS framework is inbuilt with this server. and just after installation and configuration i am able to exchange emails. No problem with it but when i execute the command "load dots" i got the following exception:

```
> load dots
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.dots.launcher.OSGiProfile
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.dots.launcher.OSGiProfile
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:434)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:672)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:358)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:638)
[08E4:0002-0B80] 07/14/2014 12:58:53 PM  Unable to access OSGiProfile class, make sure the launcher.jar is in osgi-dots directory
[08E4:0002-0B80] 07/14/2014 12:58:53 PM  Domino OSGi Tasklet Container terminated
```

But when i create a directory in domino/ directory named "osgi-dots" and copy the contents of osgi and launcher.jar and dotssec.jar files.
i got the following exception:

```
> load dots
> java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at com.ibm.dots.launcher.OSGiProfile.frameworkStarted(OSGiProfile.java:974)
    at com.ibm.dots.launcher.OSGILauncher.startOSGI(OSGILauncher.java:280)
    at com.ibm.dots.launcher.OSGILauncher.launchOSGIFramework(OSGILauncher.java:145)
[1E74:0002-1AAC] 07/14/2014 03:49:59 PM  Domino OSGi Tasklet Container started ( profile DOTS )
```

Please tell me what is this problem i am facing and what these outcomes says.

Answer (score 0):

By default DOTS is not fully installed on the server. You need to install the OpenSocial component add-on.

Part numbers for that are here.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24033984

Be sure to download the matching OpenSocial component for the Domino Server you are running. For example the V9.0 release listed here will not install on a Server installation of V9.0.1.

In case page vanishes.

```
OpenSocial component V9.0 installers

CIF0JEN
IBM Domino Social Edition OpenSocial component V9.0 32 bit for Windows English
CIF0QEN
IBM Domino Social Edition OpenSocial component V9.0 32 bit for AIX English
CIF0MEN
IBM Domino Social Edition OpenSocial component V9.0 32 bit for Linux for xSeries English
CIF0KEN
IBM Domino Social Edition OpenSocial component V9.0 64 bit for Windows English
CIF0LEN
IBM Domino Social Edition OpenSocial component V9.0 64 bit for AIX English
CIF0REN
IBM Domino Social Edition OpenSocial component V9.0 64 bit for IBMi English
CIHU1EN
IBM Domino Social Edition OpenSocial component V9.0 64 bit for Linux for xSeries English
CIF0NEN
IBM Domino Social Edition OpenSocial component V9.0 64 bit for Linux for zSeries English
```

Comment: @ Simon O'Doherty thanks for the reply man! I tried to download "CIF0JEN" but ibm imposed passport advantage to download this. They asked for some site number, and i don't have one. Is there no other way to download this??? Or what kind of account i have to download with passport advantage?

Comment: You probably need to talk to your sales contact as this is how you normally download Domino (same process).